# Constructing a vector with istream_iterators

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

I recall once seeing a clever way of using iterators to read an entire binary file into a vector.  It looked something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream source("myfile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    vector<char> data(istream_iterator(source), ???);
    // do stuff with data
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to use `vector`'s iterator range constructor by passing input iterators that specify the entire stream.  The problem is I'm not sure what to pass for the end iterator.

How do you create an `istream_iterator` for the end of a file?  Am I completely misremembering this idiom?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want the `std::istreambuf_iterator<>`, for raw input. The `std::istream_iterator<>` is for formatted input. As for the end of the file, use the stream iterator's default constructor.

```
std::ifstream source("myfile.dat", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(source)),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

**Edited** to satisfy [C++'s most vexing parse](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=767929). Thanks, @UncleBens.

Comment: Beware of the most vexing parse.

Comment: Interesting, that this won't compile for me.  I have to assign `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` to a variable or give it a parameter `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(0)`.  I wonder why.  I'm using VS2005.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the pattern I was trying to remember.

Comment: Finally, I found the answer. Pretty much the only one on SO.

Answer (score 11):

In C++11 one could:

```
std::ifstream source("myfile.dat", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> data(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(source), {});
```

This shorter form avoids the most vexing parse problem because of the `{}` argument, which removes ambiguity of it being an argument or a formal parameter.

@wilhelmtell's answer could also be updated to avoid this problem by adopting a brace initializer for `data`. Still in my view, using `{}` is more simple and turn the initialization form irrelevant.

#### EDIT

Or, if we had [`std::lvalue`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27053125/1000282) (and maybe `std::xvalue` instead of `std::move`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
constexpr T &lvalue(T &&r) noexcept { return r; }

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    vector<char> data(
        istreambuf_iterator<char>(lvalue(ifstream("myfile.dat", ios::binary))),
        {}
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @pepper_chico. Am I correct in thinking that when you use `{}` in the second argument for the data constructor the compiler determines that the type of this argument should be `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and therefore calls its default constructor `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}`? Is that what `{}` is expanded to?

Comment: @Stan Yes, it does the same as `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()`, it's an useful construction, works like `auto`, but for values (default values) instead of types alone.