# Allocating elements in C++ vector after declaration

Tags: c++, vector, resize, dynamic

Please refer to the code and comments below:

```
vector<int> v1(10);
cin>>v1[0]; // allowed
cin>>v1[1]; // allowed

// now I want v1 to hold 20 elements so the following is possible:

cin>>v1[15]>>v[19]; // how to resize the v1 so index 10 to 19 is available.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply need to resize the vector before adding the new values:

```
v1.resize(20);
```

Comment: after resize, I can take input using cin without requiring push_back?

Comment: @Gunner:  `vector<int> v1(10);` is effectively the same as `vector<int> v1; v1.resize(20);`.  That said, what do you have against `push_back` (or, what do you have against a `reserve` followed by `push_back`?)

Comment: @James: Nothing against those, but the situation is such, I would like to take input directly into the vector instead of a temporary variable. At the end, both will be same, but was wondering if there was an alternative.

Comment: @Gunner: yes - after resize you can access v1[0] through v1[19] without a push_back.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) like this:

```
v1.resize(20);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read as many values from `cin` as are available, you can use an `istream_iterator` iterator range and pass that to the `vector` range-constructor, like this:

```
#include <iterator> // for istream_iterator
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> // for cin

// ...

std::vector<int> v1( (std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin )), // extra ()
                     std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

(the extra parentheses are required to prevent ["C++ most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). Cf. also [Constructing a vector with istream_iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423361/constructing-a-vector-with-istream-iterators).

Comment: Though this isn't exactly what I want, but its an useful feature on its on accord. Under many circumstances, the first thing we would be doing is getting input into a vector after declaring it.

Answer (score 2):

vector::resize() will resize it and fill it with default constructed objects (int, in this case, so it doesn't matter).

vector::reserve() will allocate space, without filling it.

You can add additional items using, for example, push_back(), until it has however many items you want - it resizes itself as needed.

Comment: It does matter. Because it uses the `x[<newMember>] = T()` (before people complain (conceptually, exact details slightly more complex)) method of initializing the new members and INT is a POD. POD values are value initialized and thus the members are set to 0.

Comment: Note that `reserve` will not increase the size, only the capacity. Thus in the OP's case, it would not be possible to access elements 15 and 19 after a `reserve(20)`. You need `resize` for that.

Comment: @Martin: granted - but what I meant is that it's not an involved, time consuming constructor - or a constructor that you have control over.

Comment: @Steve - right - but I added that because the underlying question probably has to do with capacity, and it's almost never useful to have a vector filled with default constructed objects. I find that reserve() followed by some type of insertion is almost always what I want to do.