# initialize a vector to zeros C++/C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I know in C++11 they added the feature to initialize a variable to zero as such

```
double number = {}; // number = 0
int data{};  // data = 0
```

Is there a similar way to initialize a `std::vector` of a fixed length to all zero's?

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec(42);`

Comment: btw, this is not new in c++11, you can do this in previous versions as well

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5922797.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You don't need initialization lists for that:

```
std::vector<int> vector1(length, 0);
std::vector<double> vector2(length, 0.0);
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly state the 0 do you? just `vector(length)` should work?

Comment: @jozefg: Yes, it would work, though there is no harm in being explicit about what you want the code to do.

Comment: @ronag i wrote my own answer because being explicit in this case is not necessarily a good example if int is not the type he is working with. gereral programming is available in c++ but when i was reminded that you can omit the argument altogether, i removed my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to re-initialized Global Vector's all element with`ZERO` with efficiently without using for loops??????

Comment: Well, I just tried exactly that, and the resulting vector is full of garbage values : `std::vector<uint8_t>  inputBuffer(totalSize, 0);`

Comment: @AnkitMishra Yes, use `std:fill(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(), 0)`

Answer (score 4):

Initializing a vector having struct, class or Union can be done this way

```
std::vector<SomeStruct> someStructVect(length);
memset(someStructVect.data(), 0, sizeof(SomeStruct)*length);
```

Comment: This is OK for built-in types (`int` etc) and PODs, but will bring huge problems for classes with either **1.** virtual methods (because vtable pointer will be set to `0`) or **2.** invariant that some field is not `0` (which is usually enforced by constructors and methods).

Comment: As well as being dangerous for anything except trivial types, what you wrote is pointless: constructing the vector with size `length` already default-initialises all of the new elements. If it were needed to default-initialise all elements later, or to set them all to some other value, `std::fill()` should be used because it's actually C++ and type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of c++ you can go with `std::fill`.

*I noticed someone mentioned it as comment. But should be an answer and encourage to use standard library algorithms which are mentioned by experts, very well tested and proven.*

```
    std::vector<int> vecOfInts;
    vecOfInts.resize(10);

    std::fill(vecOfInts.begin(), vecOfInts.end(), 0);

    for (auto const& intVal : vecOfInts)
    {
        std::cout << intVal << " ";
    }
```

Comment: What's putting 10 values in your vector is the resize method, not the fill which just replaces existing values.

Comment: The OP specifies "fixed length" in his question. 10 is an example.

Comment: This is a method to assign a vector to 0's, but the OP specified 'initialize'.

Answer (score -7):

For c++: Let's say that the vector has a maximum of 100 int elements. You can initialize it this way:

int vector[100]={0};

Comment: That is **NOT** a vector.

Comment: More importantly, you actually get zero initialization for free with arrays. Try `int array[100];` — it's zero-filled.