# How to initialize pair<vector<pair<bool,int>>,vector<pair<bool,int>>> in C++11

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to initialize:

```
pair<vector<pair<bool,int>>,vector<pair<bool,int>>> pvp;
```

so that for all i:

```
pvp.first[i].first = true;
```

and

```
pvp.second[i].first = false;
```

I know that you could do this with a loop but isn't there any faster way like an [initialization for a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110130/initialize-a-vector-to-zeros-c-c11)?

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the best data structure to represent your data? Because I'm guessing it is not...

Comment: @Kevin   What is I?! How many elements should the vectors have?! What values should be assigned to objects of type int? Can you use the human language or not?!

Comment: `pair<vector<pair<bool,int>>,vector<pair<bool,int>>> pvp = {vector<pair<bool,int>>(n, {true, 0}), vector<pair<bool,int>>(n, {false, 0})};` But that's a really weird data structure to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization syntax would be:

```
pvp{ vector<pair<bool, int>>(5, { true, 0 }), vector<pair<bool, int>>(5, { false, 0 }) };
```

Now, you didn't specify any length of the array (or what the integer should be), but here's the full approach:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    pair<vector<pair<bool, int>>, vector<pair<bool, int>>> pvp{ vector<pair<bool, int>>(5, { true, 0 }), vector<pair<bool, int>>(5, { false, 0 }) };

    for (auto i : pvp.first){
        cout << (i.first ? "true" : "false") << '\n';
    }
    for (auto i : pvp.second){
        cout << (i.first ? "true" : "false") << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 true
 true
 true
 true
 true
 false
 false
 false
 false
 false
```

As already mentioned, this implementation is too complex for a simple human reader to understand. Separate it into smaller pieces, though.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I do not have a direct answer to the question, but I do not see the the question as the real problem.

Generic data structures are great, but maybe, consider a few classes, instead. That way the individual class constructers can handle the initializations as needed (in smaller pieces).

Comment: Seems like fair advice, but this would be better posted as a comment, rather than an answer. Especially since it is not "a direct answer to the question". :-)

Comment: @CodyGray - sometimes the right answer is to unask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using typedefs to make the code easier to read.

```
using MyPair = pair<bool,int>;
using MyPairs = vector<MyPair>;
pair<MyPairs,MyPairs> pvp{MyPairs{make_pair(true,10)},
                          MyPairs{make_pair(false,11)}};
```