# How can I use std::copy to read directly from a file stream to a container?

Tags: c++, stl

I ran across a cool STL example that uses istream_iterators to copy from std input (cin) to a vector.

```
vector<string> col1;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(),
    back_inserter(col));
```

How would I do something similar to read from a file-stream directly into a container?  Let's just say its a simple file with contents:

"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."

I want each word to be a separate element in the vector after the copy line.

Comment: Hint: `std::cin` is a file-stream.

Comment: in _literally exactly_ the same way.

Comment: @BoPersson: `std::cin` is not a `std::fstream`, so  your comment is ambiguous.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423361/constructing-a-vector-with-istream-iterators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `cin` with file stream object after opening the file successfully:

```
ifstream file("file.txt");

copy(istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(),
                                                 back_inserter(col));
```

In fact, you can replace `cin` with any C++ standard *input* stream.

```
std::stringstream ss("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.");

copy(istream_iterator<string>(ss), istream_iterator<string>(),
                                                 back_inserter(col));
```

Got the idea? `col` will contain words of the string which you passed to `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly the same with the fstream instance instead of cin.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the copy function is needed since the vector has a constructor with begin and end as iterators.

Thus, I think this is OK for you:

```
ifstream file("file.txt");
vector<string> col((istream_iterator<string>(file)), istream_iterator<string>());
```

The redundant () is to remove the [Most_vexing_parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)